# How prove this determinant can't zero

Tags: inequality, determinant

Let $x,y,z\neq 0$ be real numbers, show that
$$f(x,y,z）=\begin{vmatrix}
\sqrt{x^2+y^2}&|x|&|y|\\
|y|&\sqrt{y^2+z^2}&|z|\\
|x|&|z|&\sqrt{x^2+z^2}
\end{vmatrix}\neq 0$$

or  it suffcue to prove $$f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)(z^2+x^2)}+|y|^2|z|+|x|^2|z|-|xy|\sqrt{y^2+z^2}-|xy|\sqrt{x^2+z^2}-|z|^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\neq 0$$

Comment: But it totally can, though. $x = y = z = 0$

Comment: sorry,$x,y,z$ can't be equal $0$

Comment: Modify the question statement to reflect non-zero reals. It makes a world of difference.

Comment: If $x,y,z$ replace $|x|,|y|,|z|$ the problem is equivalent to the same thing without any of the absolute value occurrences, as long as you require with this re-write that $x,y,z>0.$ I don't know if this leads to a simpler solution, but at least it gives simpler algebra.

Comment: communnites: In view of my example (see answer below) are you absolutely sure the matrix has been copied correctly from whatever the source of the problem is? Maybe include a link to that source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x=y=1,\ z=0.1$ the determinant is $-0.3957...$

And for $x=y=1,z=0.5$ the determinant is $+0.1781...$

So since it is continuous in $z$ for fixed $x,y$ there is a value of $z$ between $0.1$ and $0.5$ for which $(x,y,z)=(1,1,z)$ makes the determinant zero.

Maybe the ordering in one of the rows should be different, but this can only be checked from the source of the question.

Comment: Specifically, $z = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: @Axoren Thanks for the explicit $z$ value. My slow algebraic calculator was taking to much time (for me) to find it.